# Чем грозит наличие двух и более одинаковых mac-адресов в сети?

Tags: сеть, ethernet, mac-address

Например, есть mac-spoofing. Так вот, если в сети оказалось два пользователя с одинаковыми mac-адресами, то как это повлияет на их работу? Они не смогут выходить в сеть или, наоборот, будут получать сообщения друг друга, или только один из них, что ближе к маршрутизатору будет получать информацию?

Comment: У обоих будут потери и лаги, а коммутатор будет пыхтеть и всё время перестраивать ARP-таблицу. Это если в сети нет ничего типа ну хотя бы DHCP snooping + Dynamic ARP inspection.

Comment: На практике, практически оба не будут работать, пакеты будут перестараться и отправляться роутером в разные стороны, а со стороны клиентов отсылка ответов с разных мест на один запрос, при нормальных настройках условий маршрутизации этот трафик будет отбрасываться на бордюр-роутере (снупинг).